# SignalR Hub connect authorization error

Tags: google-chrome, signalr, signalr-hub

When trying to connect to a SignalR hub running in the same web application I get a 401 error (unauthorized).  I can put a breakpoint in the OnConnected() method and see I am hitting my hub.  The error occurs in Google Chrome.  Tested in IE and it works fine.

Client code (JS):

```
    var connection = $.hubConnection();
    proxy = connection.createHubProxy('myHub');
    connection.start();  // error occurs here
```

Server code (C#)

```
public class MyHub: Hub
{
    public override Task OnConnected()
    {
        return base.OnConnected();  // I hit this breakpoint
    }

    public void AddLogItem()
    {
        Clients.All.logItemReceived("Adding a log item @ " + DateTime.Now);
    }
}
```

Error:

```
WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:50303/signalr/connect?transport=webSockets&clientProtocol=1.4&connectionToken=gEGkgEb740vzdMSFcFIfNev1d%2BFP0A9tqPaXGRT84RNSZwLDDShUKFd36fdN1Xx1heMZT3d%2BO0EkvRFtkB%2BZIwh39qcekTn94tUPyrMfX1jiIHAdhHwvGVUUJkLHTUnLxvBBPhU1FIZEn0JuLjFHYQ%3D%3D&connectionData=%5B%7B%22name%22%3A%22jcsecurehub%22%7D%5D&tid=6' failed: Error during WebSocket handshake: Unexpected response code: 401
```

Other Startup Code:

```
public class Startup
{
    public void Configuration(IAppBuilder app)
    {
        app.MapSignalR();
    }
}
```

Comment: Apart from the error you see, does everything else work? Chrome displays a 401 error with Windows Authentication because of the handshaking, but normally after that everything else works fine.

Comment: You are right.  I got hung up on this error and didn't realize everything works.